# How to Solidity pick a random value with percentage

Tags: solidity

I am working on a smart contract that need to pick true or false value (or any two value) with percentage. For example in 95% selects true but in 5% selects false. Can I do that in my contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Chainlink VRF, which is the current industry standard for generating random numbers on Solidity. You could use it to generate a random number within the range 0-100, [here's a simple guide](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf-best-practices/#getting-a-random-number-within-a-range) that shows how to do so. You would only need to change the range to be as follows:

```
randomResult = (randomness % 100);
```

To get a boolean value with a percentage probability. For example, `true` with 95% probability. You would only need to follow up with the following check:

```
bool val = randomResult <= 95;
```